# Merging Dictionaries with multiple Types, or Any / AnyObject Type

Tags: dictionary, swift

I have this Swift code for merging two Dictionaries together:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func extend(newVals: Dictionary <String, Any>) {
        for (key,value) in newVals {
            self.updateValue(value, forKey:key)
        }
    }
}
```

The line that contains `.updateValue( , forKey:)` generates the following error:

```
'protocol<>' is not convertible to 'Value'
```

Previously I had `newVals` as a `Dictionary <String, String>` and it worked fine, so my guess is the problem is caused by the use of `Any`.

My problem here is that I am using Dictionaries with a mixture of `String`s and `Int`s (and possibly other types of value later on).

Is there anyway to get this `extend` function to work with the type `Any`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to (and you can't) specify the `Any` type in the function declaration - you need to have the subtypes of the `newValues` dictionary match the dictionary it's extending:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func extend(newVals: Dictionary) {
        for (key,value) in newVals {
            self.updateValue(value, forKey:key)
        }
    }
}

var dict = ["one": 1, "two": 2, "hello": "goodbye"]
dict.extend(["three": 3])
dict.extend(["foo": "bar"])
```

`Key` and `Value` are type aliases within the `Dictionary` type that map to the specific key- and value-types of a particular instance.

Comment: You can miss out `<Key, Value>` entirely too and just say `newVals: Dictionary` here too

Comment: This extend function is being used where the Dictionary has already been declared as `Dictionary <String, Any>`. When using this `extend` function I now get the error `'Any' is not identical to 'NSObject'`??

Comment: One of the dictionaries you're using is `[String: Any]`, the other is `[String: NSObject]` - you'll need to reconcile the difference with a cast.

Comment: Although it looks like casting doesn't work: **`can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes`** - what's the source of these instances? Can you declare one of them differently at the beginning so they match?

Comment: @MikePollard Neat - didn't know it would assume the same specialization.

Comment: I am using `Any` instead of `AnyObject` because the value could be a String, an Int (or possibly anything else). Can these be safely converted to `NSObject`? Would I have to do a type check and then turn Int into an NSInteger?